# Laravel unlimited category listing

Tags: php, laravel, categories

I get this error when listing categories, can you help me?

> array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given

Category.php

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}

public function childrenCategories(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class)->with('categories');
}
```

Controller

```
public function AddView(Request $request){
    $categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->with('childrenCategories')->get();

    return view('settings.measure_type.add', 'categories');
}
```

view

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
    <li>{{ $category->name }}</li>
    <ul> @foreach ($category->childrenCategories as $childCategory)
        @include('child_category', ['../../child_category' => $childCategory])
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

child_category.blade.php

```
<li>{{ $child_category->name }}</li>

@if ($child_category->categories)
    <ul> @foreach ($child_category->categories as $childCategory)
            @include('child_category', ['child_category' => $childCategory])
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing an associative array, you are using a string as the second argument in your controller. Instead, you should pass the data to the view like the following.

```
return view('settings.measure_type.add', ['categories' => $categories]);
```